# While loop output not appearing on jupyter lab or jupyter notebook

Tags: python, while-loop, output, jupyter

I am a super noob with python. I was practicing some code and when it came to while loops this weird behavior emerged. The code involving **while** does not give output, not even an error message, on jupyter lab, or jupyter notebook. I've been work with while loop for months, and this behavior is new for me.
I am learning Python for data science. So I just installed anaconda and usually work from there.
[notebook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCPU.png)

Comment: `x` is already 5.  So `while x < 5` is going to return immediately and not do anything.  In your second loop, you have `for x in range(5):`, so you're explicitly setting x to 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 each time through th eloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you never enter the while-loop, because x is not less than five.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).